# Using Javascript clone(); to make a standalone header follow the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html structure on my pages of `one DIV` containing `two other DIVS` inside, where the first one is a smaller `header` and the other one is a `navigation` bar (`#main-template-navigation`). The both divs are static so they don't follow when you scroll the page. What I'm trying to do now is to get the navigation div follow the page on scroll. I'm using the code below to do so, however when the position is changing to fixed the website jumps up which ain't so smooth.

So my question is how to make it 'smooth'? I've been trying to use the `clone();` function but it didn't work as long as I didn't have a separate div to append it to which I would like to avoid.

```
$(function() {
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#main-template-navigation').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {

            $('#main-template-navigation').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});

        } else {

            $('#main-template-navigation').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @SamBattat Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/4vbzvxd7/3/

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, this is not the way you should do it. You should have one single header and then the CSS should change once the user has scrolled past a certain point to make the header smaller/hide certain elements.

Comment: So how differently do you want it to behave. It seems to be working for me (based on what I understood from your question)

Comment: @SamBattat well I know it works, however I don't want the page to jump up when the position is changing to fixed. So I though of maybe using clone function, but  I don't know how to append it without creating a separate div

Comment: I see what you mean. I had to add some text to the body to see the "jumping" lol https://jsfiddle.net/4vbzvxd7/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of fixing the problem:
Add a "buffer" div to the top when the fixed is added and remove it when it removed. The buffer div height matches the nav height

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/4vbzvxd7/5/

```
$(function() {
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#main-template-navigation').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {

            $('#main-template-navigation').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});

            if(!$('#main-template-navigation-container').length){
                $('<div/>',{
                    id: 'main-template-navigation-container',
                    css: {
                        height: $('#main-template-navigation').height()   
                    }
                }).prependTo('body');
            }

        } else {
            $('#main-template-navigation').css({position: 'static', top: '0px'});
            $('#main-template-navigation-container').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set the div as fixed always and define a height size, and the only change I would do if I want to start any effect.

```
  header{
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 108px;
            // set animation
            -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
            transition: all 0.4s ease;
        }
```

Look here for more info:

http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2014/05/how-to-create-an-animated-sticky-header-with-css3-and-jquery/